# Ubuntu apt-get unmet dependencies for NPM

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, apt-get

I am trying to install NPM. To do so, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

This worked successfully. I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get install npm

 Reading state information... Done
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Trying to install node-gyp leads down an endless path of "unmet dependencies".

I followed these instructions and have 0 not upgraded packages; https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

I disabled all Other Software Source and still have problems. I keep running into this issue for other packages (hhvm and mono). What can I do to resolve these issues?

Comment: npm comes with nodejs these days. Are you sure you don't already have it?

Comment: it's happening with me when I've installed nodejs v.4.0.0, but strange that I'm npm as usual :)

Comment: I tried to run NPM and got "The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install npm"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I exactly had the same symptom and error message when installing npm.

Refer to [Node Package Manager got corrupted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626383/node-package-manager-got-corrupted-in-some-way-now-it-cannot-be-installed)

You can do the following

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm ## remove existing nodejs and npm packages
sudo apt-get install curl  
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

This works on my Ubuntu 16.04.2

Answer (score 2):

Do `sudo apt-get clean` or `sudo apt-get -f install`.

`clean` clears the local cache of .deb files.

`-f` means "fix broken".

Comment: I have tried this while following this tutorial: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

I have "0 not upgraded packages", which seems to imply I should not have issues.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I had packages installed that prevented the installation of npm dependencies:

```
# apt install npm
...
 npm : Hängt ab von: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) soll aber nicht installiert werden

# apt install node-gyp
...
 node-gyp : Hängt ab von: nodejs-dev soll aber nicht installiert werden

# apt install node-gyp nodejs-dev
...
 nodejs-dev : Hängt ab von: libssl1.0-dev (>= 1.0.2) soll aber nicht installiert werden

# apt install node-gyp nodejs-dev libssl1.0-dev
...
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev libneon27-dev libssl-dev
```

So the problem was that I had these three packages installed:

```
libcurl4-openssl-dev libneon27-dev libssl-dev
```

After removing them, I could install npm without problems.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the nodejs is already installed in a newer version than the latest ubuntu, possible from a PPA. If you remove the current nodejs and install the one provided by ubuntu, then you can install npm.

You've to remove it with dpkg to avoid remove dependencies:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

Before running `npm install`, performing the following steps may help:

remove node_modules using `rm -rf node_modules/`
run `npm cache clean`

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because the `npm` package is tied to the built-in `nodejs` package.

You **do not need to install `npm`** when installing `nodejs` from nodesource, as it already includes `npm`.

Just do this:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

It will install both `node` and `npm`.

```
node -v
npm -v
```